# Event sourcing and Domain Event

Tags: microservices, event-sourcing, event-driven, domain-events

What is [Event sourcing](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html) and what is [Domain Event](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/domain-event.html).

I read both the articles and I am not be able to get it properly. So, please describe it in easy words.

And what is the difference between them?

Are domain events and event driven are same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not your fault: the literature is a mess.

Domain events, event sourcing, and event driven are three *different* ideas that happen to share the label "event".

Domain events are a domain modeling pattern; in effect making "things that happen" a first class citizen in your domain model.  Think `BookSold`, not `MouseClicked`

Event sourcing is a data modeling pattern; instead of having a domain entity with mutable properties, we have a domain entity with a history of changes.

Event driven is a communication pattern; system A publishes an event, and system B reacts.  Notice that system A and system B don't even need to know about each other; the only need a common undertanding of the event, and shared plumbing (aka middleware).